# How to see conda installed packages in Pipfile

Tags: anaconda, conda, pipenv, pipfile

According to Pipenv doc (https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv-and-other-python-distributions), one can *"reuse Conda–installed Python packages, use the `--site-packages flag`"*:

```
$ pipenv --python=/path/to/python --site-packages
```

When using the above command, the Pipfile did not get updated with the packages already installed in the conda environment specified in the `--python flag`.

1) Is this the expected behaviour of the command?

2) Is there a way to populate the Pipfile automatically?

Comment: Though not exactly what you are looking for, you can always run `pip list` inside your Conda environment, or `conda run -n myenv pip list`, or most simply `pipenv run pip list`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs, the `--site-packages` flag is used for:

> reuse Conda–installed Python packages

If you use it, the conda-installed packages will be available for you in the pipenv environment.

You can see that using `pip freeze` within your pipenv environment.

```
pipenv run python -m pip freeze

# installed packages will be listed - including conda-installed packages
```

If you don't use the `--site-packages`, you will get an empty environment.

In conclusion:

1. This will not update your `Pipfile`, and it is the expected behavior.
2. There is no automatic way to fill your `Pipfile`.